# Is there a way to request other machine sizes in Google Cloud Builds?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud Builds appears to offer three different machine sizes for running the builds, as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/pricing).

We can see that these map onto three of the available compute machine types [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types).

So our options are:

- 1 CPU, 3.75GB memory
- 8 CPU, 7.2 GB memory
- 32 CPU, 28.8 GB memory

I want to run Cypress tests as part of my build pipeline, a pattern that Google have endorsed and provide, and my requirements are for perhaps 8-16GB of memory. In order to meet that minimum, I need to request the colossal 32 CPU machine and pay accordingly. This isn't going to be viable for us because of the huge cost of an extra ~30 CPUs.

Ideally, I'd like to request the `n1-highmem-2` machine to run these tests; I think that nicely covers my needs, but it doesn't seem to be an option in Cloud Builds. I've tried my luck specifying it in the cloud builds options, but it wasn't seen as valid.

Am I misunderstanding something here? It seems absolutely bizarre to me that we can have so little memory with so, so many CPUs. Why would I want that? Why are Google so certain I'll want that that they won't even offer different shapes like highmem here?

Comment: Hello @Goldstein. Does any of the below answers [helped you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: Thanks @WytrzymałyWiktor, Sergiusz's new answer below is what I was hoping for. While it wasn't available at the time and I appreciate the other responses, I've marked that as the solution for those who come across this question today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having similar problems in 2022:
Cloud Build now also offers [private pools](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/private-pools-overview) with 15 additional machine types:

> - e2-medium
> - e2-standard-2
> - e2-standard-4
> - e2-standard-8
> - e2-standard-16
> - e2-standard-32
> - e2-highcpu-2
> - e2-highcpu-4
> - e2-highcpu-8
> - e2-highcpu-16
> - e2-highcpu-32
> - e2-highmem-2
> - e2-highmem-4
> - e2-highmem-8
> - e2-highmem-16

In @Goldstein scenario, **e2-highmem-2** with 16GB of RAM can be used for $0.01306/minute compared to $0.064/minute when using **e2-highcpu-32**.

Answer (score 0):

You can build N1 custom images using the gCloud cli tool.

A single N1 instance type is limited to 6.5GB of memory per vCPU so to get more memory you will need enable use extended memory at additional cost.

I have linked the relevant GCP documentation for your reference.

[Creating a VM Instance with a custom machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type)

[Adding extended memory to a machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type#extendedmemory)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

As of april/2021 there are 4 machine types available for Cloud Build as described in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#machinetype):

```
N1_HIGHCPU_8    Highcpu machine with 8 CPUs.
N1_HIGHCPU_32   Highcpu machine with 32 CPUs.
E2_HIGHCPU_8    Highcpu e2 machine with 8 CPUs.
E2_HIGHCPU_32   Highcpu e2 machine with 32 CPUs.
```

---

### Original Answer

Cloud Build provides two high-CPU virtual machine types to run your builds: 8 CPUs and 32 CPUs. The default machine type is 1 CPU. Requesting a high-CPU virtual machine may increase the startup time of your build. Add the machineType option to request a virtual machine with a higher CPU.

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#options

So no, these are the only three options available.